# base64 pdf link not opening in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf

I encoded a pdf into base64 and trying to load that base64encoded pdf in to browser like

```
  data = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+base64encodedpdf;
  window.open(data);
```

It is opening in chrome. But  it is not opening in firefox.

pls help me.

Comment: Theoretically firefox supports such URIs, cf. [*data URIs* on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs). Thus, you may want to supply a complete sample for reproduction and inspection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify Firefox applications options From :

[image]

To :

[image]